# guardar datos en tablas diferentes - php

Tags: php

Buen dia, estoy recibiendo 3 datos de un formulario , el primero se llama nombre y es una variable , el segundo se llama dato1 y dato2 pero son arrays hasta ahi bien , **pero ahora lo que no he logrado hacer es que la variable nombre me guarde en la tabla ingresos y los arrays dato1 y dato2 me guarde en la tabla detalles_ingreso.**

```js
<?php

include '../../bd/global.php';

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

if($_POST['METHOD']=='POST_prueba'){
    unset($_POST['METHOD']);
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
    $query="insert into ingresos(nombre) values ('$nombre')";
    $queryAutoIncrement="select MAX(id_ingreso) as id_ingreso from ingresos";
    $resultado=metodoPost($query, $queryAutoIncrement);
    echo json_encode($resultado);
        $num_elementos=0;
        $sw=true;
        while ($num_elementos < count($id_detalle))
        {
            $sql_detalle = "INSERT INTO detalle_ingresos(id_ingreso, dato1, dato2) VALUES ('$idingresonew', '$idarticulo[$num_elementos]','$dato1[$num_elementos]','$dato2[$num_elementos]')";
            ejecutarConsulta($sql_detalle) or $sw = false;
            $num_elementos=$num_elementos + 1;
        }
        
    return $sw;
        
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    exit();
}

header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");


?>
```

Base de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podes publicar tus modelos?

Comment: solo necesito acomodar el metodo post que muestro con la pregunta que realice ya que es una Api y la información se envia desde otro framework diferente a php.

Comment: `count($id_ingreso)`???  Y que es `$id_ingreso`?  no lo veo definido... y que es `metodoPost()`?  que hace?... no se, lo veo todo muy raro y poco preciso

Comment: lo que necesito es que los datos que recibe  el metodo "POST_prueba" que son nombre, dato1 y dato2, se guarden en las siguientes tablas relacionadas: nombre en la tabla ingresos y dato1 y dato2 en la tabla detalle_ingreso , he intentado pero aun no me funciona.

Comment: Dices que dato_1 y dato_2 son arrays. No son aceptados por el tipo de datos especificado **varchar**, que recibe cadenas de caracteres. Necesitarías serializarlos y, eventualmente, contar con una longitud mucho mayor que 50

Comment: los arrays se van guardando serializados por ejemplo en la primera tabla se debe guardar el campo nombre pero en la tabla detalle si se envian dos arrays estos quedan en cada fila pero relacionado la primer tabla y el nombre que se guardo con el id_ingreso.  Pero no he logrado hacer eso con el metodo POST que estoy mostrando.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir la definición de las tablas? ¿Son campos `AUTOINCREMENT` tanto `id_detalle` como `id_ingreso`?

Comment: He dado respuesta a tu duda y, además, te sugiero una manera de iterar por la matriz de valores.

Answer (score 0):

Para empezar te recomiendo activar en tu entorno de desarrollo TODAS las advertencias y errores, ya sea por la salida al navegador o en el registro de error del servidor web, para que puedas ver y depurar lo que estás haciendo mal conforme desarrollas la aplicación.

Una aplicación bien desarrollada no debería mostrar ningún mensaje de advertencia.

---

**Pregunta: pero ahora lo que no he logrado hacer es que la variable `nombre` me guarde en la tabla `ingresos` y las matrices `dato1` y `dato2` me guarde en la tabla `detalles_ingreso`**

El motivo por el que no se guarda `nombre` en la tabla `ingresos` es un misterio mientras no compartas la implementación de la función `metodoPost()`.

En cuanto al motivo por el que tampoco se guardan los valores de `dato1` y `dato1` es debido a tu primer mensaje de advertencia:

> **Warning**:  Undefined variable `$id_ingreso` in ...

Se refiere a esta línea:

```
while ($num_elementos < count($id_ingreso))
```

En PHP 8, además, te saldría un error fatal indicando que el parámetro de `count()` debería ser contable o una matriz, pero proporcionas `null` (variable no definida):

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught TypeError: `count()`: Argument #1 (`$var`) must be of type `Countable`|`array`, `null` given in ...

Pero en PHP 7.4 e inferiores el resultado de `count(null)` es `0`, por lo que  ese bucle no se ejecutará ni una vez. Por eso no se ejecutará nunca el código del interior del bucle, aunque desconozcamos también la implementación de la función `ejecutarConsulta()`.

Imagino que quieres iterar por cada valor recibido en ambas matrices, por lo que lo que deberías hacer es lo siguiente:

```
/* Comprobamos que haya el mismo número de elementos en las matrices */
if (count($_POST["dato1"]) === count($_POST["dato2"])) {
    foreach ($_POST["dato1"] as $indice => $valor) {
        $dato1 = escapar_sql($_POST["dato1"][$indice]);
        $dato2 = escapar_sql($_POST["dato1"][$indice]);
        $sql_detalle = "
            INSERT INTO detalle_ingresos (
                id_ingreso,
                dato1,
                dato2
            ) VALUES (
                '$idingresonew',
                '$dato1',
                '$dato2'
            )
        ";
        ejecutarConsulta($sql_detalle) or $sw = false;
        $num_elementos++;
    }
}
```

Tu código puede sufrir los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL). Debes hacer uso de, al menos, una función para escapar el SQL (que yo he llamado `escapar_sql()`) ya que parece que no usas consultas preparadas.

Nota también que en tu SQL estabas definiendo tres campos para insertar, pero proporcionabas cuatro. Todos estos errores pasan inadvertidos porque no tienes un control de errores adecuado.

Como no sé si usas PDO, mysqli u otro sistema para acceder a la base de datos no puedo ayudarte con las funciones de escapado del SQL ni con la gestión de errores.